# The activity I intent to makes the app crash, throwing the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=14; index=14

Tags: java, android

The error I'm getting :

```
 Process: com.example.numerology, PID: 4012
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=14; index=14
    at com.example.numerology.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:90)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText e1 = findViewById(R.id.name);
    final EditText e2 = findViewById(R.id.date);
    final EditText e3 = findViewById(R.id.month);
    final EditText e4 = findViewById(R.id.year);
    Button b = findViewById(R.id.button);
 b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            char[] n = e1.getText().toString().toCharArray();
            int date = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
            int month = Integer.parseInt(e3.getText().toString());
            int year = Integer.parseInt(e4.getText().toString());
            int nn = 0;
            int driver = date, conductor = date + month + year;
            int temp, k = 0;
                Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            i1.putExtra("NN", nn);
            i1.putExtra("Driver", driver);
            i1.putExtra("Conductor", conductor);
            startActivity(i1);
        }
    });
```

This is the major part of the code I'm using, I think the problem is related to the character array. 
This is how I'm using the char array:

```
 if (n[i] == 'f' || n[i] == 'F' || n[i] == 'p' || n[i] == 'P') {
                    nn += 8;
                }
```

So this activity does pop up on the screen but when I press the button to jump to the next activity the app crashes leaving the error I specified above.
Gonna need some help fixing this, Thank you.

Comment: Maybe what u need is `n[i - 1]`? I not sure since u didn't show all the necessary code.

Comment: I've got about 5 such if statements all working with the array and all of them are in a for loop which start at i=0.

Comment: The relevant code is at line 90 of MainActivity.java. You should post it here.

Comment: Also, this looks suspicious to me: `conductor = date + month + year`. (This is not related to the problem, however.)

Comment: these are all integers. I'm just adding them up in another one to use that value at many other places and in calculations.

Comment: for (i = 1; i <= e1.getText().toString().length(); i++) {

Comment: It seems like you are accessing an index that doesn't exist. @SamratTrehan is that last comment you did the line 90 code? If yes, edit your question and add at the end of it. That should be part of the question and not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes start from `0` and end at `length-1`. Your code below is accessing it wrong as you are using `<=` with length, thus your last access for `i` will be `length` and not `length-1`. So change your loop

```
for (i = 1; i <= e1.getText().toString().length(); i++)
```

to

```
int len = e1.getText().toString().length();
for (i = 0; i < len ; i++)
```